# Java pad string with space

Tags: java, string-formatting, padding

I am attempting to add padding to a string, however I cannot figure out how to do this. My goal is to have something that looks like this:

> Home:       email@gmail.com (7 spaces after the colon)

The above has `"Home:"` hardcoded and should have 7 spaces along with a variable for the email. Here is what I have so far:

```
return String.format("Home:%7s", email);
```

My understanding was that `%7s` was to add left padding with a value of 7, then I have the `s` for the string I want to include after the padding. Can someone help to correct me?

How it looks is much like this:

```
Home:email@gmail.com
```

So what's happening is when I have something like this, everything looks fine:

```
return String.format("Home:%7s", "email");
```

The second I add my variable rather than hardcoding "email", I lose the padding completely.

Comment: Hope this will help: https://www.baeldung.com/java-pad-string

Comment: [ask]: You're supposed to research your own: search the web for `java pad string` will lead to tutorials like _Baeldung.com_  If still not found, clarify what you found, tried and still erroneous or missing.

Comment: I have and I cannot figure it out, thus posting here with the example that I have tried as well as asking for clarification.

Comment: Did you read the _javadoc_ for method [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) in class `java.lang.String`? It contains a [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) to a very detailed explanation of the syntax.

Comment: @hc_dev I updated my question above. I am not sure as to how to have a string before the padding as well as substitute the string variable to present the email.

Comment: @Abra I have done so, and I have updated my question.

Comment: What do yoy mean by _pad_ or _padding_? Please see my answer and *clarify your desired "padding"* !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this might help

```
    String email = "abc@jhkj.com";
    System.out.println(String.format("Home:%1$3s%s%s", "", email));
```

Output:
`Home:   abc@jhkj.com`

Comment: This does help yes, I appreciate it. I had only thought that I needed the '%7s' to indicate the desired spacing I need?

Comment: Your format-literal (template) actually adds 3 spaces like `String.format("%3s", "")`. I think we should clarify what we understand by _padding_  Because a string of 12 chars padded to anything below, like 7 or 3, will result in all 12 chars output.

Comment: It’s just a terminology I agree with u @hc_dev, but here we should understand the expectation of user rather than focusing on which terminology they have used.

Comment: @Its Andrew u could have use MARGIN to define that additional space before mail I’d.

Comment: @Koushlendra Exactly _terminology_ is how we (devs) communicate in code. Agree: focus on users' expectations! Moreover: __clarify with them first then explain and (re)direct them__ like "You asked for `MARGIN` not `padding`. Imagine others seeking for SO-help and found this __question "Java pad string with space"  answered: "use a fixed MARGIN by adding 3 spaces"`". What did they learn about `java string padding` then?

Comment: @ItsAndrew could u please update ur question instead of pad u could use ***margin***

Answer (score 1):

Your *template* expressed by format-literal seems to work. See [demo on IDEone](https://ideone.com/fi6dtW):

```java
String expected = "Home: email@gmail.com"; // (7 spaces after the colon)
String email = "email@gmail.com";
assert expected == String.format("Home:%7s", email);
```

#### Use of variable & Inserting a space

Notice how the `email` variable was passed as *argument* to the `format` method to merge it into the *template*.

To insert a **space** after colon and before the padding, just add it in the *template* like this: `String.format("Home: %7s", email)`

#### Spacing

The comment

> // (7 spaces after the colon)

can be achieved by padding: Padding an empty string `""` to 7 with format `%7s`. Result is always 7 spaces. Thus you can directly inject 7 spaces by inserting a constant
`static final String SPACES_7 = "       ";`
after the colon, like:
`String ouput = "Home:" + SPACES_7 + email;`
But then there is no padding-effect.

This is called **spacing**. Adding space between elements. The effective output here's always 5+7 long plus variable email-length. The spacing is 7, between your *label* "Home:" and *value* `email`.

#### Padding

If you pad a *string* of 15 chars to 7 chars, then the effect will be *no padding*, because the *string* already is longer than given padding-size.

In your question you desired to

> have the `s` [placeholder] for the *string* I want to include after the padding

⚠️ **Padding** is not (added) before or after a *string*!

[Padding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Width_field) **expands** output-space for the *string* to guarantee **minimum width** (the opposite of truncating = maximum width).
It does so by filling up the space (left or right) with a pad-char .
The purpose of padding is usually alignment (left, right, center).

In your email use-case this would add characters (here: space) to have a **fixed-sized output** and align email-addresses, so they line-up when multiple lines are stacked vertically.

To achieve effective padding, you should choose the padding-size greater than or equal to the string. Otherwise a longer string may outgrow the padding-size (which is not the purpose of padding).

See the [demo on IDEone](https://ideone.com/dFgbhY) which will add 5 spaces to the left when email is 15 long to achieve a fixed-size output, or right-aligned, or just padding of 20.

#### See also

- [Java docs for `String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))
- formatter strings: [template syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)